# how can I get ride of 'cannot read property of undefined' error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, components, scheduler

I want implement calendar with reactjs but this error occurs:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_setDocumentWidth' of undefined
```

The code in app.js is as follow:

```
let dndContext = new DnDContext(sources, ResourceEvents);

this.currentArea = -1;
schedulerData._setDocumentWidth(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
this.state = {
     visible: false,
     dndContext: dndContext,
}
```

And the code in schedulerData is:

```
_setDocumentWidth(documentWidth) {
    if (documentWidth >= 0) {
        this.documentWidth = documentWidth;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure that schedulerData is defined here ? It looks like it's not declared, or imported. Is schedulerData defined in another file ?